# Эффект размытости в слайдере

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделан этот слайдер:
[joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/)
Что то типа:
две картинки, и, которая маленькая, смещается через background-position?
Я как не искал не нашёл background-position в блоках с картинками, как же тогда это сделано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/tree/master/demos/

Comment: Я понимаю, что есть готовые слайдеры, но мне хотелось бы понять принцип его работы.